# 'On the roundabout' or 'in the roundabout'?

Tags: prepositions

I got a TomTom navigator as a present and set it to narrate in English (Irish voice). Every time I'm about to go left or right in a roundabout it says: ”Go right *on* the roundabout, first exit”

The choice of preposition (*on*) strikes me as odd. I would've expected an *in* but perhaps that's just because how we say in my country (Sweden; where *on* would be plain wrong).

After some searching on the internet I realize that both *in the roundabout* and *on the roundabout* are commonly used. However, I can't really tell if they're completely interchangeable or if one of them should be picked in favour of the other depending on the context.

Comment: I don't think *any* native speakers would say *Go right **in** the roundabout*. There's nothing obviously wrong with ***on***, but I'd have thought ***at*** would be far more common (in BrE, at least, and we're more into roundabouts than Americans).

Comment: @Fumble - Depends on which part of America you're in. In the northeastern U.S., roundabouts are plentiful, although they are called [_rotaries_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotaries_in_Massachusetts) there.

Comment: @J.R.♦: [*There are an estimated 26,000 roundabouts in the UK*](http://www.roundaboutsusa.com/history.html). That webpage goes on to say *Today, the number of modern roundabouts in the USA has jumped to around 4,800 (as of December 2015)* (and - somewhat surprisingly, perhaps, *There are over 200 roundabouts constructed in Utah*, so what few there are in the US certainly aren't all in the NE).

Comment: @Fumble - Sure, I didn't mean to say that New England is the only place you'll find them in the U.S. (As a matter of fact, less than a year ago, they just built a new one on a street where I frequently go jogging.) But I think your average driver from New England will be much more accustomed to seeing them than your average driver in Utah, and (more importantly from an English/learner's perspective) I don't know how common the term _rotary_ is outside of New England.

Comment: As a child in the mid-60s, I moved to a [UK "new town"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_towns_in_the_United_Kingdom), where just about every junction that either was or might become significant in terms of (future) traffic flow was designed around the then "new-fangled" idea of roundabouts. A decade later I moved to another new town, so they've always been commonplace to me. Brits rarely use *rotary* except as a less common alternative to *gyratory* (a ***major*** roundabout-based junction in the context of fast-moving traffic such as motorways, usually with ***multiple*** crossing routes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are driving, you are driving *on* the road, not "in" the road. However you could be playing *in* the road, meaning between the curbs is a close vicinity.

> Go right **on** the roundabout, and take the first exit.

A possible usage for *in* though it may be a stretch:

> Go 3 miles until you see the "For Sale" sign **in** the roundabout, then...

meaning the sign is on land inside the roundabout.

Comment: Got it. Being _on_ the roundabout is no different from being _on_ the road. However, it's seems fairly easy to find the phrase _in the roundabout_ on the internet. Perhaps it's exclusive for non British English? Marking as answered.

Comment: But you have to consider what it is that is "in the roundabout" in such examples.